# Tag tabs are toast (layout bug)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, layout

I visited https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2 and couldn't find the Unanswered tab:

[image]

This appears to be a problem where the tabs are long enough that they get pushed onto an invisible next line, which I can actually drag-select to cause to scroll:

[image]

The tabs also reappear at certain browser zoom levels, again suggesting that they're *just barely* too long.

Conditions:

- Tested in current Safari and Chrome on Mac OS X.
- Occurs on all tags that currently have 1 featured question.

Comment: works fine for me on Windows/Chrome m

Comment: The spacing between the letters is wider than what I get; that's the issue.

Comment: Fine with Firefox on Windows.

Comment: This should be fixed as of about 1 hour ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This should be fixed as of about 1 hour ago. – Ben Collins♦

Looks fixed to me. Psst, that comment should have been an answer!